# Bluetooth headphones connected to PC via cable (music) AND to my phone via BT (answering calls). Is it possible?

Tags: bluetooth, headphones, smartphone

I am unable to google anything about following scenario, so I am asking here:

I am looking for bluetooth and cable headphones (with microphone). I will connect them to the PC 3,5mm audio jack via cable and will listen to music played by some audio player. Then, I will have my (Android) smartphone paired with headphones via BT and in case of incoming call, I will answer it just by touching some button on headphones (or similar) (with muting PC audio).

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible to have the scenario which you looking for.

Both were analog signals from your phone and from your PC.

your PC will be emitting output analog signal from your audio player which is a software with in your PC. These signals can be interrupted only with some other signal with in your PC managed by other software within your PC.

Connect your phone to your PC and you should search for some software to handled the request to your phone instead of managing files alone. It should have user interface to attend calls too.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but actually there could be solution - not with 3.5mm audio jack, but with USB cable. Some [Plantronics headphones](http://www.amazon.com/Plantronics-Blackwire-C720-Wired-Headset/dp/B009KZ367A/) could do the job based on its descriptions.